# Get Objects to Arraylist, DAO

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I want to write Objects from a Jlist(with DefaultListModel) into Arraylist, so that I can use it to save/load (stream) them.

```
GUI
private DefaultListModel<Meeting> dlm = new DefaultListModel<Meeting>();
private JList list = new JList<>(dlm);  

    btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Meeting m;
            m = new Meeting((Date)spinner.getValue(), textArea.getText());
            dlm.addElement(m);
        }
    });
```

Now Jlist has Objects, datatype is Meeting.
How can I get these Objects into the Arraylist, it should be for DAO?

```
DAO

private GUI g;

private void writeFile() {

    ArrayList<Meeting> mList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object meeting : Arrays.asList(g.dlm.toArray())) 
    {
        mList.add((Meeting)meeting);

        System.out.println(meeting);
    }
}
```

I tried to set dlm to private also public at the GUI

The next step is to create a file and write Arraylist into it
At the end I imagine a file that stores the Arraylist

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: “*Now Jlist has Objects*”—No your `JList` has a *raw type*. Just declare `list` as `JList<Meeting>` instead. To get its contents as `List`, you can simply use `ArrayList<Meeting> mList = Collections.list(g.dlm.elements());`—no need for manual copying.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will be getting a NullPointerException with the current code. You need the instance of GUI to get access to dlm. Add a method `setGUI(GUI g)` to the DAO  and set the instance of GUI using this method before calling `writeFile()` in the DAO. dlm should be public for his to work.

```
public void setGUI(GUI g) {
    this.g = g;
}
```

I wouldn't say this is the best design, but it should work.

To have a better design, convert the model values to an ArrayList in the GUI itself and call the `writeFile()` method with the ArrayList as parameter.

DAO

```
 // Don't need this 
 //private GUI g;

private void writeFile(ArrayList<Meeting> mList) {
    // Code to save to a file 

}
```